# Slim 500 server error while using method inside route

Tags: php, composer-php, slim, autoload, psr-4

So i did try namespace without slim and it was working without any problem but when in slim keeps showing :

```
500 server error
```

Composer.json:

```
{
  "require":{
    "slim/slim":"2.*",
    "slim/extras":"2.*",
    "twig/twig":"1.*",
    "slim/pdo": "~1.6"
  },
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
      "Ultimateboard\\": "src"
    }
  }
}
```

MainController.php

```
namespace Ultimateboard;

class MainController {


  function __construct(){

  }

  public function index(){
    echo 'hello main controller index';
  }
}
```

index.php

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'app/loads/routes.php';
```

how i have did try to call the methods :

1 Routes.php

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(
  array(
    'view'=> new \Slim\Extras\Views\Twig(),
    'debug'=> true
  )
);
$app->get('/',Ultimateboard\MainController);
$app->get('/testing',function(){
  echo 'testing works';
});
$app->run();
```

or

Routes.php

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(
  array(
    'view'=> new \Slim\Extras\Views\Twig(),
    'debug'=> true
  )
);
$app->get('/',function(){
 use \Ultimateboard\MainController as MainController;
 new MainController()->index();
 });
$app->get('/testing',function(){
  echo 'testing works';
});
$app->run();
```

directory structure:

[image]

Maybe im missing something or going in conflict with something , did try many answers on different sites but nuthing worked thats why posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resvoled by changing the namespace to

```
namespace \Ultimateboard\Controllers;
```

and routes to :

```
$app->get('/',function() use ($app){
   (new Ultimateboard\Controllers\Maincontroller())->index();
});
```